# Ole Frame can not open excel files in Linux environment

Tags: java, linux, apache-poi, eclipse-rcp, ole

I setup an application(RCP) with an OLE frame for inplace editing.OleFrame cannot open excel files in linux(CentOS7) environment.I am using **Apache OpenOffice 4.1.2.**

```
private void createExcelPart(Shell shell) 
{ 
    //OleFrame is actually a Composite for placing OLE controls 
    OleFrame oleFrame = new OleFrame(shell,SWT.NONE); 

    //OleClientSite provides a place to embed an OLE object into a container, where the OLE object represented by "Excel.Sheet" is Excel. 
    OleClientSite clientSite = new OleClientSite(oleFrame,SWT.NONE,"Excel.Sheet"); 

    setValueForA1Cell(clientSite); 

    //OleClientSite action when displaying OLE object, the action here is OLEIVERB_SHOW, display 
    clientSite.doVerb(OLE.OLEIVERB_SHOW); 
}
```

**Target Environment:**

*BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
 Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64*

> MESSAGE Application error

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The import org.eclipse.swt.ole cannot be resolved

OleFrame cannot be resolved to a type
OleClientSite cannot be resolved to a type
OLE cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Please give me any solution.Thanks

Comment: OleFrame is Windows only.

Comment: @greg-449 please give me any alternative solutions.

Comment: I don't know of any

Comment: OpenOffice has some OLE stuff, you could look into it to see how they do it as they are open source. There will likely be some incompatibility no matter what you do as OLE is a Microsoft proprietary extension.

Comment: Please provide me any other link to helpful.